MeshFunctions and MeshShading manipulation to get the desired plot

I need to draw the above plot. Below are my codes, which give me a little faulty result. How to correct them and get the desired result? or is there any better way to do so?
method-1
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, x], Function[{x, y}, x]}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshShading -> {{Directive[Black, Dashed], 
    Directive[Red, Dotted]}, {Directive[Black], Directive[Red]}}]


method-2
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}, 
 ColorFunction -> {Function[{x, y}, If[x > 0, Red, Black]], 
   Function[{x, y}, If[x > 0, Cyan, Green]]}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]



It is recommend to use Show. {Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4 π, 4 π},     MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, x]}, Mesh -> {{0}},     MeshShading -> {Directive@{Dotted, Black}, Black}],    Plot[Cos[x], {x, -4 π, 4 π},     MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, x]}, Mesh -> {{0}},     MeshShading -> {Directive@{Dashed, Red}, Red}]} // Show

Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}
 , {x, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}
 , PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}
 , Mesh -> {{0}}
 , MeshShading -> {Directive @@ {Thin, Dashed}, Thick}
 ]




Since MeshShading will affect all the plots, it is recommend to use MapThreadetc. with Show for more style control.
style11 = 
  Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[6], 
    AbsoluteDashing[{1, 10}, 0, "Round"], Black};
style12 = Black;
style21 = Directive@{Dashed, Red};
style22 = Red;
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4 π, 4 π}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {style11, style12}];
plot2 = 
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, -4 π, 4 π}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshShading -> {style21, style22}]; 
Show[plot1, plot2]



Original Answer
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, x], Function[{x, y}, x]}, 
     Mesh -> {{0}, {0}}, MeshShading -> {{Dashed, Dashed}, {Black, Red}}]

Edited
On reflection the previous answer was poor. This is cut down version:
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, MeshFunctions -> (#1 &), Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Dashed, Thick}]



Thank you very much @ubpdqn
just one more question: What should I change if I use four functions instead of two to get a similar plot?

@user444 I suggest you try and see. Good luck
